# Need help in permission in sharepoint form library

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working with SharePoint 2010. I need some help in regarding permissions:

1. Only current user can see his document created by him, he should not see other document.
2. Other user apart from creator of document should not see or should not delete the document.
3. While approver will see the document, he can only view the document he should not delete the document.
4. And while approver will see the document he should not get the add new document option(For this i have given permission Read Only, View Only permission but still while approver login to system he get add new document option.)

How can I give permissions described above?

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with code? Otherwise this question belongs to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many question i'll answer one-by-one.
1) The best way to do is by creating new view or modifying view of library, set filter criteria to "Created by is equal to [Me]" & save. The creater of document can only see this document.
2) If others are not able to see the documents then how can they edit or delete.
3) For this you need to create new permission level which have rights of approve item,open library.
4) Just simple not check the add items checkbox in permission level.

I hope this will help you!